# Who are anonymous users?

Tags: discussion

Every now and then while doing reviews, I'll get a suggested edit submitted by an **anonymous user**.  How are these people associated with the site?  I thought that you had to have at least an account to make any edits on any SE site.

I often find that the edits made by these anonymous users have no benefit to the post they are editing or conflict with the originals authors intent.  Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image: Anonymous User Edit]

In this case, I skipped this review since I couldn't determine if it was clashing with the orginal authors intent or not.

Who are these users?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Everyone, including those who aren't registered (and excluding banned users) can propose edits, and they'll show up as anonymous users. Such users can also answer questions, but they have to supply a name.